# DataGrid nested within a DataGrid issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am getting a "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead" error and I am not sure why.

I am trying to nest a datagrid inside a datagrid. If I just use a textblock it has no issue, but once I assign the value and click on one of the parent datagrid elements I get the above error.

Here is my xaml:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dgSREducation" Background="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Link" Binding="{Binding Link}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notification Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Notification}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compare Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Compare}"/>
                 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"/>
              </DataGrid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Words}"></TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Education_Click"/>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
     </DataGrid.Resources>
  </DataGrid>
```

My Class for all of this is:

```
class SREducationData
{
   public NamedIDData Type { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public string Link { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<ConditionData> Conditions { get; set; }

   public string Words { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
class ConditionData
{
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public NamedIDData Notification { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public NamedIDData Compare { get; set; }
}
```

When my program initially loads I am setting the ItemSource in code by doing `dgSREducation.ItemsSource = display;` where display is `ObservableCollection<SREducationData> display;`

As soon as I click on one of dgSREducation's elements I get the error and a blank datagrid appears beneath that element. Any thoughts on what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Data Grid : Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987064/wpf-data-grid-operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, you did not put the nested datagrid's columns inside of <DataGrid.Columns>.

Change:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notification Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Notification}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compare Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Compare}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

To:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notification Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Notification}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compare Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Compare}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!