# Setting DataGrid ItemsSource causes XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, xaml, revit-api

so I have a problem with an XAML file I'm using; I'm trying to use a DataGrid to add a table view of the properties for an element the user selects. How I'm currently attempting to do this is that I have a list containing the appropriate pairs that gets populated on user click, and then the ItemsSource is set to that list. I have tried changing the details of this implementation (binding the ItemsSource without a reference to the datagrid itself, etc, but sooner or later they all seem to hit the same error)[image: Call Stack Trace when attempting to set ItemsSource]

The weird thing (to me) is that after a few clicks on different elements (and hitting 'continue' when the exception pops up) the grid does populate with data, although it often seems to "freeze" (showing the same data for a few elements before finally refreshing a couple of elements later, no exceptions are thrown, but the behaviour is definitely inconsistent)

.xaml.cs

```
// ParameterPair is a custom class that contains 2 string fields (name, value)
        public List<ParameterPair> AllParameters { get; private set; } = new List<ParameterPair>();


                // called (only) when a new element is click
                // ... code to populate AllParameters here
                // definitely populates properly, checked through debugging
                this.dGrid.ItemsSource = AllParameters;
```

.xaml

```
<Page ...>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Add Constraint">
            <Grid Name="loginBlock" Grid.Row="0">                        

        <GroupBox Header="Properties"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Margin="10, 10, 10, 0">
                        <StackPanel>


                            <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dGrid" 
                            Height="300" Margin="12"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                               />
                    </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Manage Constraints" />
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't seem to be from your databinding, but from the xaml markup somewhere.
Your GroupBox doesn't seem to have closing brackets. 
And is this a custom DataGrid? Since it's referenced as "controls:DataGrid" unlike your other controls. There might be something wrong in its markup.

Comment: I tried to remove the "controls:" part as well (as I had originally seen it used in a tutorial and was myself unsure of why it's like this), but nothing changed. The open GroupBox was just a formatting error of mine (sorry!). I tried removing everything but the page (and leaving the DataGrid in) and still got the error. I agree that it's probably a problem with the xaml though somehow, since I'm a complete newbie with it sadly. When I looked around the only thing that looked hopeful was maybe something to do with importing libraries properly and so on, but nothing I could materialize.

Comment: And it's not a custom DataGrid no

Comment: Fixed it, thanks, your comment was a great hint. I think I'll try looking at the XAML file way more now when ominous exceptions pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I fixed it. Turns out **AutoGenerateColumns="true"** was the culprit. I came upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987064/wpf-data-grid-operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use?rq=1) in my frustration, and tried manually setting the columns, which seems to work perfectly fine, just binding the columns to the appropriate fields in the class being used for the list.

```
                            <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid"
                            Height="300" Margin="12"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                               >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

P.S. I will avoid choosing this as my answer as it is largely a workaround, hopefully someone more experienced will come and give a more thorough and concise solution (maybe myself later on in this project...)